# Using the turtle package, is it possible to create a function asking for an argument? (And then use it for the .onkeypress method)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, pong

I tried myself at making the Pong project using the turtle package on Python.

I know how to make the code work (using 4 different functions taking no arguments, for each paddle and directions), but my question is if and how can I do it with this idea.

Here's the code I'm attempting to make work :

```
def move_paddle_up(paddle):
        y = paddle.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddle.sety(y)
    
def move_paddle_down(paddle):
        y = paddle.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddle.sety(y)

#Keyboard binding movement
screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(move_paddle_up(left_pad), "w")
screen.onkeypress(move_paddle_down(left_pad), "s")
screen.onkeypress(move_paddle_up(right_pad), "Up")
screen.onkeypress(move_paddle_down(right_pad), "Down")
```

When the screen is launched, the paddles won't move if I press the associated keys.

With the way of using the 4 different functions, it works.

It's just that I am curious to know how I should call or define the arguments in such a function.

Comment: You are calling your movement functions ONCE, immediately, and passing their return value (which is None) as the handler to be called when the key is pressed.  You have to somehow pass actual functions here - one way is `lambda: move_paddle_up(left_pad)` and similar variations.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand... I'm still a fairly beginner,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see then that is it quite more work than just creating 4 functions.

I think you got the wrong take home message.  @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam's use of `functools.partial()` is spot on, but we can fit it into your existing code with less overhead:

```
from functools import partial

# ...

def move_paddle_up(paddle):
    paddle.sety(paddle.ycor() + 20)

def move_paddle_down(paddle):
    paddle.sety(paddle.ycor() - 20)

# Keyboard binding movement
screen.onkeypress(partial(move_paddle_up, left_pad), "w")
screen.onkeypress(partial(move_paddle_down, left_pad), "s")
screen.onkeypress(partial(move_paddle_up, right_pad), "Up")
screen.onkeypress(partial(move_paddle_down, right_pad), "Down")
screen.listen()

# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onkeypress` method doesn't allow to pass a function with arguments, however you can use `functools.partial` for this kind of situations.

You can create a function which handles all type of keyboard presses, and pass that function as a `partial function`.
Let's create that function first:

```py
def move_paddle(paddle, key_pressed):

    def move_paddle_up(paddle):
            y = paddle.ycor()
            y += 20
            paddle.sety(y)
        
    def move_paddle_down(paddle):
            y = paddle.ycor()
            y -= 20
            paddle.sety(y)

    if paddle == left_pad:
       if key_pressed == "w":
          move_paddle_up(paddle)
       elif key_pressed == "s":
          move_paddle_down(paddle)

    elif paddle == right_pad:
       if key_pressed == "Up":
          move_paddle_up(paddle)
       elif key_pressed == "Down":
          move_paddle_down(paddle)
```

Now we can use this function with `functools.partial`:

```py
import functools
[...]
screen.onkeypress(functools.partial(move_paddle,[left_pad,"w"]), key="w")
screen.onkeypress(functools.partial(move_paddle,[left_pad,"s"]), key="s")
screen.onkeypress(functools.partial(move_paddle,[right_pad,"Up"]), key="Up")
screen.onkeypress(functools.partial(move_paddle,[right_pad,"Down"]), key="Down")
```

The way [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) works:
It takes a `function` with some `arguments` (*args, it's actually an unpacked list), and then creates a new function which is the previous function that gets those args as input:

```py
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I see then that is it quite more work than just creating 4 functions. Haha. Thanks for the functool.partial information as well!

Comment: You're very welcome @m3.b  I'm glad my answer was useful for you. Hopefully it is worth an upvote or maybe to be chosen as the correct answer✅ . Cheers.