# Is it possible to put python's turtle into a function?

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics

First of all, I'm sorry if I made a stupid mistake because I'm a beginner. Please forgive me

I started making a "game" in python using the turtle class for homework.
Here is the code:

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
window.setup(width=800, height=800)
window.bgcolor("black")
window.tracer(0)

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.speed(0)
player.shape("square")
player.color("red")
player.penup()
player.goto(0, 0)

def objectup(t):
    y = t.ycor()
    y += 30
    t.sety(y)

objectup(player)
window.onkeypress(objectup(player), "w")

window.listen()
while True:
    window.update()
```

I don't get an error message, but the enemy still won't go up, and I don't know why

What's wrong with this code?
Thanks in advance (if i made a mistake, sorry for my english)

I got it to work by adding `y = player.ycor()` to the function. But this way I can't move other objects with the same function.
I have no idea, so I'm asking here to see if anyone can help a beginner

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the turtle package, is it possible to create a function asking for an argument? (And then use it for the .onkeypress method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474979/using-the-turtle-package-is-it-possible-to-create-a-function-asking-for-an-argu)

Answer (score 0):

`window.onkeypress(objectup(player), "w")` means you call `objectup(player)` and you pass the value it returns to `window.onkeypress(..., 'w')`. But it doesn't return anything (which means it returns `None`). You need to pass a function to `window.onkeypress` that will be called by turtle, something like:

```
window.onkeypress(objectup, 'w')
```

But if you want it to work for different objects you need to make function that returns a function:

```
def objectup(t):
    def wrapped():
        y = t.ycor()
        y += 30
        t.sety(y)
    return wrapped

window.onkeypress(objectup(player), 'w')
```